# “Waiting for Debugger” without be on debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Android studio changed something and now ALWAYS that i run my app it get stuck in a screen "waiting for debbuger"

[image]

then i need to go at "chooser process" and attach the debuger to my app. BUT IT IS VERY ANNOYING mainly because i dont want to debug i just pressed RUN

how can i fix it and stop this bad error at least when i'm not debuging

Comment: Do put your app to the debug mode in your phone is in developer options.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have added your app in `Select app to be debugged` in `Settings -> Developer Options -> Select app to be debugged`

To resolve this, simply go to **Select app to be debugged** and click on `No apps`

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of Attach Debugger to Android Process

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to revoke the debugging options from Developer options.

- Disconnect cable/wifi from Android Studio
- Close the Android Studio
- Revoke debugging option.

  - Developer Options -> Disable and then enable USB Debugging
  - Revoke USB debugging authorizations
  - You need to give authorizations for your phone again once you connect
- Connect your phone to your computer
- Re-open Android Studio
- Check run configuration, make sure you choose the default activity to be executed.
- Try running your application again